# Correct writing for Laudato Si

Tags: contemporary-latin

I am wondering about writing the name of a document written by Pope Francis that goes by the Latin name Laudato si'. Someone has told me that the i requires an accent aigu but I see it written as above, with an apostrophe after it. Help?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps surprisingly, this title is not Latin! It's in Umbrian (*), a Romance language (or dialect depending who you ask) descended from Latin.

In this case, the Pope is quoting a song written by Saint Francis of Assisi, popularly known as "the Canticle of the Sun". The second word is *si*, which I believe is the Oscan equivalent to Standard (Tuscan) Italian *sii* "you are". So I'm guessing the apostrophe indicates that (from a mainstream Italian perspective) there's a letter missing.

Language aside, though, [the official text from the Vatican](http://w2.vatican.va/content/francesco/la/encyclicals/documents/papa-francesco_20150524_enciclica-laudato-si.html) confirms that it's supposed to be an apostrophe, not an acute.

(*) Not to be confused with the Sabellic language also called Umbrian, spoken several centuries earlier in the same area.

Comment: +1! An interesting note is that the Canticle is the first work of Italian literature whose author is known.

Comment: Oh thanks so much - really helpful!

Comment: By the way, Wiktionary says *sii* is an imperative: is this true? I only know *sei* as "you are", but my Italian is rudimentary.

Comment: @Cerberus: Yep, that's right!

Comment: @VincenzoOliva: OK! Now I wonder, is *sii* pronounced disyllabically?

Comment: @Cerberus: Yes indeed, _sì-i_.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva: Noted!